# What is the best way to implement a request/response protocol using akka and scala?

Tags: scala, architecture, concurrency, guice, akka

I've been studying about how I could develop a distributed architecture that implements the protocol request/response using the concept of concurrency through actors.

I concluded that the best way to do this is by creating a response system with synchronous handling of Futures/Promises, and soon after the response, leaving an open channel to receive notifications.

Thus an architecture that would work exactly like a inbox message.

It has some problems.

Thus I would have to maintain two endpoints (actors in the two layers)?

**The Problem:**
The view module requests that a particular element is processed. She sends this command to be processed via RemoteActor on the application server. This server should immediately return the promise that it will notify you when the element is processed. After this, the view module will be waiting the notification of completion of processing.

How do you see this problem?

I am using Scala, Akka and Google Guice.

I believe it is a generic problem that everyone can make use of their solutions. Excuse me if I'm hurting the terms of stackoverflow site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to distract from any good answers you may get on Akka, because I unfortunately don't know much about Akka and it's distributed actors features, but I'd like to ask if you've considered any alternatives.

It seems that you basically need an asynchronous RPC library. There are two powerful libraries written in Scala that I know of that may satisfy your requirements - http://sna-projects.com/norbert/ and http://twitter.github.com/finagle/. Finagle gives some really powerful combinators for expressing asynchronous computation dependencies and registering listeners on futures. I'm currently maintaining Norbert, which we use at LinkedIn for some of our distributed systems, such as search.

Comment: Cool projects, I will have to look into Norbert. Akka provides an awesome replacement for some concurrency features of scala core, and libraries to do networking. Finagle and Norbert are full-on frameworks to build clustered network services. Someday, an equivalent sort of project may emerge from Akka. Which tool to pick depends on the use case.

Answer (score 4):

```
//On "server" node
class SomeActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case messageToRemoteActor => self reply_? TypeOfResponseMessage()
  }
}

Actor.remote.register("myRemoteActor", actorOf[SomeActor])

//On "client" node
val remoteActor = Actor.remote.actorFor("myRemoteActor", "hostnameOrIpOfNodeContainingTheActorAbove", port)

val f: Future[TypeOfResponseMessage] = remoteActor !!! messageToRemoteActor

f.onComplete( _.value.get match {
  case Left(exception) => handle(exception)
  case Right(result) => handle(result)
})
```

Comment: what is the default implementation used in the receive method in actor?

Comment: Default implementation of what?

Comment: You answered my question when you edit your response. =) Thanks! I have a problem described in this question. Maybe you can help me. [StackOverflowError during serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416222/akka-stackoverflowerror-during-object-serialization)

Comment: Is this still the way to do it, and if so, what do I need to import to access the !!! operator?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use one of 0MQ's REQ-REP sockets?

https://github.com/zcox/akka-zeromq-java

That way you solve your immediate problem and at the same time, begin learn an architecture that will take you a long way and supports communications with clients written in many languages.

For an example of where this might lead look at http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2009/05/22/lift-amqp-with-rabbitmq-and-scala-tutorial-and-screencast/

Note that I am **NOT** suggesting that you use AMQP today since a RabbitMQ broker would be overkill for your immediate problem. Rather, I am suggesting that you invest your time in using an architecture (message queueing) that will pay you dividends in the long run.

Comment: I considered using 0MQ in our projects. It would be a great solution for communication between modules and development platforms. But as it is an internal architecture of a module, I believe it would be a waste of time and resources to use a kind technology. The Jonas Boner team, creator of the Akka, is working on a project called [TypeSafe](http://typesafe.com/), which will provide an enterprise platform for communication between modules. In this case, I believe that using Scala and Akka seems wiser for this architecture.