# Akka - StackOverflowError during object serialization

Tags: java, scala, serialization, neo4j, akka

I'm with a problem that extends for more than 2 days. When I'm exchanging messages between actors, is accusing the JVM stack overflow.

My message is an object with many links (10000+ child objects linked together in a linked list). Namely, an object with Neo4J relationships.

The error is this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.Bits.putLong(Bits.java:108)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeLong(ObjectOutputStream.java:1928)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeLong(ObjectOutputStream.java:788)
    at java.util.Date.writeObject(Date.java:1303)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
```

Does anyone have any solution for this?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you should add the neo4j and java tags to get the attention of more people...

Comment: @Christian thanks, I'll do it

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your data structure? IMHO Neo4j-Relationships are not serializable as they are live objects connected to a graph-database? You might just store their id's but then the graph store on the other end must be exactly in sync with the originating one.

Comment: It seems that this problem is common! See that http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4152790

Comment: @Michael_Hunger: I actually abstract the relationships between data from the Neo4J. I use the concept of Transfer Objects (TO). In these objects, I create cyclic dependencies among themselves. But the problem is not these cyclic dependencies. It seems that what affects is the depth of the relationship because some of them act as linked lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `java.util.LinkedList`, or a custom linked list of your own? If the latter, you need to write a custom `writeObject()` method for it that avoids the recursion that would happen if you didn't have one.

Comment: I don't implement any data structure. I'm using only scala collections.

Comment: @ricardogobbo OK so you need to look down the stack trace to see what classes are involved in this apparent recursion, and post that information here.

Comment: I believe this is the solution. I realized that there are links that resemble a LinkedList. In other words, I understood what you were saying xD. Now Testing!

Answer (score -1):

The likely candidate for the problem is an object which has a reference to itself. Given your expression of the domain I suspect a child has a linked list which includes itself, or a cyclic reference. That is, one of the nodes it is linked to has a link to it in turn.

Comment: Hi, it does not happen, I reviewed a lot before posting my question. The object is related to one another as a trail of georeferenced points from the previous point and the next point. The first point has no point before, and the last point has no next point.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Cyclic object graphs are specially handled by Serialization. Specifically, they don't cause recursion.

Comment: So what is the problem knowing that there is still no recursion between objects?

Comment: @ricardo see my answer? There's not much point in appending your comments and questions to a wrong answer.