# How to handle StackOverflowError happended when serialize a big object?

Tags: java, serialization, stack-overflow

Here is my java code:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null; 
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(pathName);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(index);
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogManager.writeLogToFile(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The index is an instance of inverted document index by myself. I have built the object index in memory, but when I pass it to the method writeObject(index), I get the error StackOverflowError. My question is: Why does this error happen after that I have built the object in the memory?

Suppose that the data structure of index is as follow:

```
class InvertedIndex{
    private HashMap<String, PostList> index;
}
class PostList{
    private int size;
    private PostNode first;
}
class PostNode{
    private String key;
    private double weight;
    private PostNode next;
}
```

To avoid recursive call, I overwrite the method writeObject and readObject of the PostList because it may be a very long list:

```
class PostList{
     private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
            PostNode temp = first;
            while(temp != null){
                  out.writeObject(temp);
                  temp = temp.getNext();
            }
     }
     private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            in.defaultReadObject();
    }
}
```

Then I get two questions:

- out.writeObject(temp); Because temp has a reference to the next node, when I write temp, recursive call will also happen. The same situation will continue even if I overwrite the writeObject method of PostNode with defaultWriteObject. Am I right? If so, what can I do to avoid this recursive call?
- How to overwrite the method readObject()?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing what the index is. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416222/akka-stackoverflowerror-during-object-serialization

Comment: This could help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438875/stackoverflowerror-when-serializing-an-object-in-java

Comment: I think my problem is that the post list of the index is a long linked list according to your advice. Thanks for your help. @assylias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the class you're serializing, but my guess would be that the object graph is too complex. Java's default serialization mechanism works recursively through the object graph; that is, if you have object A with a reference to B, and you serialize A, it'll have to walk to B and serialize that. If B then references C, and C references D, and so on, then it's possible for the recursive algorithm to have to go so deep that it causes a stack overflow.

If that's what's causing your problem, you should write your own `readObject` and `writeObject` which avoid this recursive building, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deeply nested object structure, then that will require a deep stack to traverse. YOu should see this in the exception stack trace. `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` are not particularly frugal with stack space.

If you're trying to serialise something like a linked list, then it is better to implement `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that iterate over the list rather than recurse.

Comment: I try to overwrite the methods `readObject` and `writeObject` according to your advice and I get new problems which is shown above. Can your show me how to overwrite the two methods or give me the resource on web? I find something in [ling](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) , but I think my problem is more complex. @Tom Hawtin - tackline

Answer (score 0):

Your readObject() method doesn't match your writeObject() method, so it probably doesn't work at all, and your writeObject() method doesn't add any value to default serialization. You would be better off without both.

The recursion problem comes fom the PostNode class, not the PostList class, and you haven't actually done anything about it yet. You need a PostNode.writeObject() that traverses the list explicitly, and a symmetrical readObject() method, and a transient 'next' field.

Comment: But setting the `next` field transient means that the next field will not be serialized. If so, when I deserialize a post node, how can I know who is the next? @EJP

Comment: @jerry_sjtu it will be serialized by the loop. As a matter of fact, your present code serializes the list twice: once because of the non-transient 'next' field, and once because of your lop, which is in the wrong class. Yur de-serialization loop should set the next field to the next object in the stream, and if that is null, break.